# Is there a way to automatically get an e-mail notification about answers on all of my questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications

I love this site and the community, and I would like to be informed immediately when I receive new answers to my questions.

It would be preferable to have an automatic way to enable e-mail notifications on all of my questions, but I would be ok with enabling it manually on new questions. I just can't find that feature on the site.

Where can I enable this feature?